# Custom action chooser on a FAB button click

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-intent-chooser

I'd like to display kind of custom chooser (similar to the share intent chooser) on a fab button click event.

The thing is that it should contain custom items with custom intent actions for each of the displayed items. I mean, instead of containing several items referencing intents that open other apps, I'd like to have a custom camera image item for opening the camera, a custom microphone image item for opening a micro recorder and the same for recording a video and importing files from internal memory. It would be something like the following picture from Google Drive:

Do you know how can I create this customised action chooser??

Comment: you can design a custome dialog with all icons and on click of fab button open that dialog

Comment: @TejasPandya yes I know, but I'd like to make it as an action-chooser if possible

Comment: like opening from bottom with slide up animation ?

Comment: You have to use BottomSheet for this.

Comment: @SurenderKumar thanks, I will try it!

Comment: yes @TejasPandya I think it is BottomSheet as SurenderKumar said

Comment: yes it is a bottomsheet . but im asking you about your dialog behaviour .  is it same as bottomshet or you want something else

Comment: @TejasPandya I think it is the same, I want the 'window' to move up from the bottom of the screen and then display the 4 clickable options with a title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for this Purpose Bottom Sheet.

Here is the complete tutorial for Bottom Sheet. All three types are detailed discussed there according to your scenario. [URL](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/)

Here is the official [doc](https://materialdoc.com/components/bottom-sheets/) please have to look at this.